# Javascript - how do I check regex to ensure a string contains at least one sequence of letters/numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out the correct regex for detecting a pattern that looks something like `2d1h30m10s` where any of them are valid, such as `1h` or `1h30m` or `30m` or `10s` or any combination of those. Is regex the right tool here?

I'm trying to understand it and no matter what I do, I keep getting `false` back from the these different tests:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2][h])([1-6][0-9][m])([1-6][0-9][s])\d$/.test('2d1h10m10s')
/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2][h])([1-6][0-9][m])([1-6][0-9][s])\d$/.test('10m10s')
/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2][h])([1-6][0-9][m])([1-6][0-9][s])\d$/.test('10s')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Two problems: the `1[0-2][h]` requires *two* hour digits, and the trailing `\d$` doesn't match any of the inputs (you'd need a trailing digit in each string tested).

Comment: All your patterns end with `\d`, but none of the strings end with a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make each section of the regexp optional, so you can omit that unit.

You need to take `[h]` out of one of the alternatives -- you match `12h` but not `01h`.

You shouldn't have `\d` at the end.

You're not allowing single-digit minutes or seconds. There's also no need for 60s or 60m, since that's 1m and 1h.

```
/^((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])h)?([1-5]?[0-9]m)?([1-5]?[0-9]s)?$/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Hekk2T/3)

There's no need to put `h`, `m`, and `s` inside square brackets, since they're just single characters.

Note that since each unit is optional, this will also match an empty string. You should check for this separately from the regexp.

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Thankyou so much for helping out with this. I'm still new to Regex so this was super helpful :)

Comment: what about if the example is something like `5m5s`?

Comment: Thanks, fixxed that.

Comment: awesome :) I've been tinkering around and I might have a case with needing a 4th in there like `1d20h30m10s` and I've tried something like this: `/^(([1-9]?[1-9])d)?(([1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9])h)?([1-5]?[0-9]m)?([1-5]?[0-9]s)?$/` and it's not giving me the desired result?

Comment: It should be `([1-9]?[0-9]d)?`, so you match `10d`. You've also changed the `h` part from my answer.

Comment: Oh woops, you're right. That ended up doing the trick :) I can update my question to reflect the "d" for day part

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one will work

```
\d+\w+
```

If I understand you correctly that you are trying to test a string contain characters following numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^(\d{0,2}[hms]){0,3}$
```

examples:
https://regex101.com/r/NV6oEu/1

Answer (score 0):

I think the expression you're looking for is :

```
/^((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])h)?((([0-5]?[0-9])|60)m)?((([0-5]?[0-9])|60)s)?$/
```

Your original expression has two primary problems : 1. the `\d` at the end, and 2. capturing scope (note the extra parens in my expression).

This will also capture : 1h13s